# printing Kriging rmse value from an object

Tags: openmdao, kriging

I am working on surrogate modeling and having a problem with printing rmse value of the kriging surrogate object. It is inside an optimizer class and I want to print out rmse like in the last code in the documentation [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/surrogates/kriging.html?highlight=_metadata).

Code is [here](https://github.com/TufanAkba/surrogate_article/blob/13e75aa2690e4fa0d5fe39c24f340ae4ba76875c/MDAOMetaModel_Opt.py#L115)

- surr is the surrogate class, I want to get rmse value of the output from this class
- surrOpt is the parent class, performs surrogate-based optimization.

Comment: I see a mistake in the code you posted in lines 115-6. The surrOpt component doesn't have a .surr. This should be:   `print(prob.model.surr._metadata('Tfo')['rmse'][0, 0])`.  I don't know if this is the error you were getting though, without seeing the exception text or the results.

Comment: Thanks, @KennethMoore ! That was the mistake.